# knockout js drop down list not showing my binding within a foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am not getting any errors, but for some reason (likely simple) I can't get values to show up in my drop down list.

My knockout vm:

```
function UserRecruitingViewModel(apiBaseUrl, userId) {
var self = this;
self.orgs = ko.observableArray();
//ddl org view switcher stuff
self.orgDdl = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedOrg = ko.observable();
var DropdownOrg = function (name, guid) {
    this.orgName = name;
    this.orgId = guid;
};

//pull initial data
$.getJSON(apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId, function (data) {
    //alert(data);
    $.each(data, function () {
        //alert(data);
        var dropdownOrg = new DropdownOrg();
        var org = new Organization();
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            //alert("in foreach");

            if (k == "UserGuid") {
                org.userGuid = v;
            }
            if (k == "OrgGuid") {
                dropdownOrg.orgId = v;
                org.orgGuid = v;
            }
            if (k == "OrgName") {
                dropdownOrg.name = v;
                org.orgName = v;
            }
            if (k == "IsHiring") {
                org.isHiring = v;
            }
            if (k == "Blurb") {
                org.blurb = v;
            }
            //alert("k var: "+k); //field name
            //alert("v var "+v); //field value
            //alert("data var " + data); //array of objects (3)
            //alert(org);

        });
        alert("ddl " + dropdownOrg.name);
        self.orgDdl.push(dropdownOrg);
        self.orgs.push(org);
    });
});
}
```

in the `alert("ddl " + dropdownOrg.name)` I am seeing the correct values. 
On my page I have this:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" data-bind="foreach: orgs">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>
                    Viewing:
                    <select class="form-control"
                            data-bind="options: $parent.orgDdl(), optionsText: orgName, value: orgGuid, optionsCaption: 'Change...'"></select>
                </p>
...snip...
```

When I pull up the page in a browser I get the alerts showing the proper data, but in the ddl I see 4 options: "Change..." and 3 blank options. Inspecting the elements showing the values are not in there.

Any idea where I am messing up the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I am not sure why this was they case, but I had to change the following:

In the VM:

```
var DropdownOrg = function (name, orgId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.orgId = orgId;
};
```

On the page:

```
<select class="form-control"
        data-bind="options: $root.orgDdl, optionsText: 'name'"></select>
```

In the get request (in the VM):

```
 //pull initial data
$.getJSON(apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        var dropdownOrg = new DropdownOrg();
        var org = new Organization();
        $.each(this, function (k, v) {
            if (k == "UserGuid") {
                org.userGuid = v;
            }
            if (k == "OrgId") {
                dropdownOrg.orgId = v;
                org.orgId = v;
            }
            if (k == "OrgName") {
                dropdownOrg.name = v;
                org.orgName = v;
            }
            if (k == "IsHiring") {
                org.isHiring = v;
            }
            if (k == "Blurb") {
                org.blurb = v;
            }
        });
        self.orgDdl.push(dropdownOrg);
        self.orgs.push(org);
    });
});
```

After throwing in a bunch of alerts and strigifying a bunch of JSON I saw that I had some names in my json objects that did not match. I thought I had to follow the naming I set in the DropDownOrg object (I did change it to match, but see the original question for the old one), but it turns out it was basing the name off of how I was assigning it in the foreach loop inside the ajax get request. Seems odd to me, so if anyone wants to chime in on why this happens, feel free!